# Did Blockchain just ripped me of my bitcoin?

Tags: blockchain.info, phishing

I just completed my backup phrase security setup with blockchain after I was prompted to click finish. As soon as I click it the account confirmed a transaction I did not do transferring almost all my bitcoin to an unknown address. Could someone explain to me what happened and if I can get back my fund?

Comment: Do you have a wallet ID or transaction ID you could share with us?

Comment: bb52b31132c25be2a5626d62fb652ee144750418df090e357c887e8efdcb511f

Comment: That was an email I got

Comment: Here are the details of that transaction: https://blockchain.info/tx/bb52b31132c25be2a5626d62fb652ee144750418df090e357c887e8efdcb511f

It seems to be for about about $0.29.   Do you think someone stole your 30 cents?

Comment: https://blockchain.info/tx/bb52b31132c25be2a5626d62fb652ee144750418df090e357c887e8efdcb511f

Comment: When I clicked it that this is the URL I was directed

Comment: No I am new to bitcoin and was trying to get familiar with the system and this happens. I want to know what happen so I donot make such I mistake if I am dealing with huge sums

Answer (score 1):

I would expect that Blockchain sets up your backup and security when you create an account. If you got prompted to put in your wallet information at a later time, that would have almost certainly been a phishing attack. I suspect that you were on a website that was not blockchain.info and the mock security setup provided the information to empty your account to your attacker.